# What is the right method for a Random List of Sub Values From a List? Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What is the correct code for getting a realy random sublist (with size X) of a List with Integers?
{1,2,5,7,12,18,71,72,73} -> get a sublist e.g with 4 items
->Result: {1,5,71,73}

I was trying to solve it with `Random.nextInt`, but as my first list is not in a row, it's not possible.
What would be the correct solution?

Comment: Is it allowed to repeat elements from the source list or not?

Comment: both solutions would be interesting.

Comment: `Collections#shuffle`, where you can then sublist/"slice" the start of the list away. Repeat as necessary until the collection is depleted

Comment: Your question got closed because you tagged it Java and there was an existing Java answer. The Kotlin-preferred way of doing it is different than how you'd do it in Java.

Answer (score 6):

If we can take the same element repeatedly:

```kotlin
List(x) { list.random() }
```

If we cannot:

```kotlin
list.asSequence()
    .shuffled()
    .take(x)
    .toList()
```